# Transfer selected row ID from one page to another

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

*First Page:*

**Context Menu And Passing Parameter:**

```
<p:contextMenu for="tbl">

                        <p:menuitem value="History Alarm"  icon="ui-icon-search"  outcome="alarmMap">
                            <f:param name="siteId" value="#{dwnSite.test.id}" />
                        </p:menuitem>

 </p:contextMenu>
```

### The Datatable:

```
<p:dataTable  id="tbl" value="#{bean.sites}" selection="#{bean.test}" selectionMode="single"  rowKey="#{dwn.id}" >  

  <p:column >                                   
   <h:outputText value="#{dwn.id}"/>
  </p:column>
```

*Second Page:*

```
 <f:metadata>
         <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.searchFeatureVal}" />
 </f:metadata>
```

How to transfer row id of datatable from one page to another? When I try to show it in dialogbox in same page it works.

Comment: Where do you navigate to the second page?

Comment: @Kukeltje in the same application.

Comment: Where in your **code** do you want to navigate to the second page

Comment: Or in other words, show what you tried

Comment: @Kukeltje I have edited. Sorry for confusion .`<p:menuitem value="History Alarm"  icon="ui-icon-search"  outcome="alarmMap">
                            <f:param name="siteId" value="#{dwnSite.test.id}" />
                        </p:menuitem>`

Comment: You put your selection in bean.test and read it from dwnSite.test.id?

Comment: @Kukeltje they are different bean and pages. one is dwnSite and another is bean

Comment: Sorry,  but if your code is so difficult to comprehend, it is hard to help. We are not clairvoyant. Maybe others can help.

Comment: Do you want to pass the id from the context menu?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Yes I am trying to pass Id or any value of datatabe. I am still trying but the value is null as if when I select row in datatable no value is set.

Comment: Use an `action` method in the `p:menuItem` and perform a redirection there, passing the selection id  as a url parameter.

Comment: BTW, you miss the `var` value in your `p:dataTable`. Your posted code won't never work.

Comment: I actually removed it. I am trying the post suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a *POST* instead and process the url in the bean, where your selection is kept. Should work like this:

```
<p:menuitem value="History Alarm" icon="ui-icon-search" action="#{bean.performRedirect}" />
```

And the method to be invoked in the bean:

```
public void performRedirect(){
    //Go to the detail view with the selected id as url parameter
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .redirect("detail.xhtml?id=" + test.getId());
}
```